# Definition of co-RE class

Tags: terminology, computability

I know that the definition of RE class is: $\ RE = \left \{  L \subseteq \Sigma ^{*} | \text{Exists M which accepts L} \right \}$

Can someone explain in the same notation the definition of co-RE.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try google?

Comment: @Louis I did, but it is not explained in groups notation but in language notation.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of coRE is
$$ coRE = \{L\subseteq\Sigma^*|\text{Exists $M$ which accepts $\Sigma^* \setminus L$}\}. $$

Comment: Is this definition equivalent to "Does not exists M which accepts L" ?

Comment: No, it is very different.

Comment: For a given language L which belongs to coRE exists M which rejects every word w that does not belong to L or never stop on w ?

Comment: A language $L$ is in coRE iff its complement $\Sigma^* \setminus L$ is in RE. Every other question you can answer yourself using simple logical manipulations.